# Why can I only call this function once?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build switches that create an array and have this so far:

```
const [playgroundFilters, setPlaygroundFilters] = useState([initialF]);

  const updateItem = (whichvalue, newvalue) => {
    let g = playgroundFilters[0];
    g[whichvalue] = newvalue;
    setPlaygroundFilters(g, ...playgroundFilters.slice());
    console.log(playgroundFilters);
  };
```

When I call up `updateItem` onPress it works once and every subsequent time I get an error "undefined is not an object evaluating g"

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you passing `playgroundFilters.splice()` two times?

Comment: you are not setting playgroundfilters to an array. Also you should use find instead of findIndex in this context, and 0 is never equal to -1

Comment: @HarshSaini that was a mistake from the copy paste. g is first, then plagroundFilters.splice()

Comment: @AsyncAwaitFetch I borrowed some other code and commented it out. var  index is not used here

Comment: Still `plagroundFilters.splice()` will only return `[]`, what do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

1. setPlaygroundFilters expects an array so you would need to call it like that

```
setPlaygroundFilters([g, ...playgroundFilters.slice()]);
```

instead of

```
setPlaygroundFilters(g, ...playgroundFilters.slice());
```

2. I'm not sure you actually wants to use `.slice()` like that here, since it just returns the same (cloned) array.

Comment: Right, slice isn't needed. `...` makes a copy of the array, so you're making a copy of a copy.